# Injecting DLL and printing a message

Tags: c, dll, code-injection

I'm dealing with 2 new things: writing a DLL and injecting it in another process. I think I inject it successfully because if I try to delete it I get a message that tells me it is used by another program.

I followed this steps in Visual Studio 2008 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx but I wrote it in C, not C++.

And this is the code

```
DWORD 
APIENTRY
DllMain(
        HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
        )
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    Sleep(5000); // added this to make sure I see it when it happens
    return TRUE;
}
```

I created an application that references the DLL just like in the MSDN documentation said and it works (it prints Hello World).

At each step in my DLL injection program I check for errors and print them. So I know that no function fails.
I check the exit code and it is 1927086080 which I don't know what means.
I don't know if it's needed, but here is the C source for my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD procId = 0;   
    DWORD pathLen = 0;
    DWORD writeProcMemory = 0;
    DWORD exitCode = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = NULL;
    HANDLE hDll = NULL;
    HANDLE hThread = NULL;

    LPVOID baseAdr = NULL;
    LPVOID fAdr = NULL;

    procId = atoi((char*)argv[1]); 
    pathLen = strlen((LPCSTR)argv[2]);

    if(0 == pathLen)
    {
        printf("Check DLL path\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Open process
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
        0,
        procId);

    if(NULL == hProc)
    {
        printf("OpenProcess failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n", 
            GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate memory
    baseAdr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc,
        0,
        pathLen + 1,
        MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    if(NULL == baseAdr)
    {
        printf("VirtualAllocEx failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 0;
    }

    // write my dll path in the memory I just allocated
    if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProc,
        baseAdr,
        argv[2],
        pathLen + 1,
        0))
    {
        printf("WriteProcessMemory failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc,
            baseAdr,
            0,
            MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 0;
    }

    // get kernel32.dll 
    hDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));

    if(NULL == hDll)
    {
        printf("LoadLibrary failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc,
            baseAdr,
            0,
            MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 0;
    }

    // get LoadLibraryA entry point
    fAdr = GetProcAddress(hDll,
        "LoadLibraryA");

    if(NULL == fAdr)
    {
        printf("GetProcAddress failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc,
            baseAdr,
            0,
            MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 0;
    }

    // create remote thread
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc,
        0,
        0,
        fAdr,
        baseAdr,
        0,
        0);

    if(NULL == hThread)
    {
        printf("CreateRemoteThread failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProc,
            baseAdr,
            0,
            MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProc);
        return 0;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 
        INFINITE);
    if(GetExitCodeThread(hThread,
        &exitCode))
    {
        printf("exit code = %d\n",
            exitCode);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("GetExitCode failed\nGetLastError() = %d\n",
            GetLastError());
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProc,
        baseAdr,
        0,
        MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I inject a shellcode (with a slightly different program than the one above) into a process, I can see in process explorer how my shell code starts running and that the victim process is his parent. Here, I see nothing, but again, it's the first time I'm working with DLLs. 
But it still gets loaded because I can't delete the dll file until I kill the victim process.

Also, when I run my injection program, I can see it doing nothing for 5 seconds so it's like the printf is skipped.

Doing this on Windows 7 x64. I know that there are cases in which CreateRemoteThread isn't working on Windows 7, but I use it in my shell code injection and it works and I use the same targets here.

UPDATE: changing my DLL to call ExitProcess(0); kills the victim process, so it all comes down to me not knowing how to print something.

How can I get it to print something?

Comment: Error checking in your injector program doesn't get you very far.  The injected code runs in another process, you can't see its errors and you certainly can't count on printf() working.  At least inject yourself first so you can actually see output and have a shot at using the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get messages from your DLL but you use `printf`. How can you see DLL's `printf` output? You better write your information to a file.

```
#define LOG_FILE L"C:\\MyLogFile.txt"

void WriteLog(char* text)
{
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(LOG_FILE, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD written;
    WriteFile(hfile, text, strlen(text), &written, NULL);
    WriteFile(hfile, "\r\n", 2, &written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hfile);
}

void WriteLog(wchar_t* text)
{
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(LOG_FILE, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD written;
    WriteFile(hfile, text, wcslen(text) * 2, &written, NULL);
    WriteFile(hfile, L"\r\n", 4, &written, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hfile);
}
```

Replace all your `printf` calls with my function and see what happens actually. By the way, if you have thread in your DLL you can write log every second that will ensure you your code works. You can add time into log file too.

I think if you have enough privilege to inject a DLL into a process, nothing will stop you. Change your code and tell me what happens in log file.

Good luck

Comment: Well, now that you say it, it makes sense that printf can't do nothing that I could see. I run my program from the command line. If I open a new command prompt I can't create a thread into that process (CreatRemoteThread fails with error code 5) even if I my injection program has Administrator rights. That can be bypassed with RtlCreateUserThread, but for now I just want to get this right.

Comment: I remember that I injected DLL even into services.exe process. As far as I know, in simple words, if your process belongs to user "mustafa", then you can inject DLL to any other process that belongs to user "mustafa". I remember that I was used to test my injection with Windows calculator. After injection, I used to open Process Explorer and see if calculator has my DLL loaded into its memory or not.

Comment: CreateRemoteThread will fail in many cases due to Windows Vista/7/8 Session Separation regardless of the rights given to your program. This explains it a bit http://securityxploded.com/ntcreatethreadex.php